# Mootools jquery's blockUI equivalent

Tags: javascript, mootools, blockui

I am searching for jquery's plugin blockUI functionality for mootools. Do You know some plugin or simple way to block browser for a given time by mootools ?

Comment: block what? the UI thread? modal the screen? have you tried the mootools forge? have you looked at mootools-more?

Comment: I need block browser for 20 seconds for user, with countdown and information please wait, something like that:
`setTimeout(function() {
           $.unblockUI({
                onUnblock: function(){
                     $.ajax({
                         url: 'x4-wynik-walki.php',
                         [...]
                    });
                }
            })
       },10000);'
`

Comment: I think, I have just find what I need: the overlay plugin by David Walsh. I need now figure out how to put on top of overlay a box with countdown and set timeout for 20 sec. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: have a look at this plugin i wrote- https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/Modal - does not even need any js as such, will work with just markup - though you can do pretty much whatever you like with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started. http://jsfiddle.net/5BCPS/

taken it out of my plugin here: https://github.com/DimitarChristoff/Modal/blob/master/Source/js/Modal.js

```
(function() {

this.Modal = {};

Element.implement({
    diffuse: function(position){
        return this.setStyles({
            position: position || 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%'
        });
    }
});

Modal.Overlay = new Class({

    Implements: [Events, Options],

    options: {
        zIndex: 900000,
        opacity: .3,
        backgroundColor: '#555',
        fx: {
            duration: 300
        }
    },

    initialize: function(container, options){
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.container = document.id(container);
        var self = this;
        this.element = new Element('div', {
            'class': 'overlay',
            styles: {
                display: 'none',
                opacity: 0,
                zIndex: this.options.zIndex,
                backgroundColor: this.options.backgroundColor
            },
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    self.fireEvent("overlayClick");
                }
            },
            tween: this.options.fx
        }).diffuse('fixed').inject(this.container);
        return this;
    },

    show: function(){
        this.element.setStyle("display", "block").fade(this.options.opacity);
        return this.fireEvent("show");
    },

    hide: function(){
        this.element.fade(this.options.opacity).get("tween").chain(function() {
            this.element.setStyle("display", "none");
        });
        return this.fireEvent("hide");
    }

});

})();

var modal = new Modal.Overlay(document.body, {
    hideAfter: 5,
    onHide: function() {
        // do something.
    }
}).show();


modal.hide.delay(3000, modal);
```

all you need is what you display on top / counter. thats just plain js.

Comment: Thank You !! I don't know why I didn't use Your plugin... I saw him many times... Time for testing and usage.